# Update all with a join of child attributes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How I can perform a mass update for cache_attribute `:cached_comment_infos` stored on my Posts

It would be something like this:

```
Post.joins(:comments).where(id: post_ids).update_all(
  cached_comment_infos: self.comments.pluck(:author_name, :reference).map { |v| v.join("/") }.join(", ")
)
```

The output expected for each Post should be something like this : `"John Doe/3242, Tom Jed/6264"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want `update_all`. Update_all will update all records to one value.

https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

Example given in the docs is setting all `Customer`'s `wants_email` to `true`

```
  Customer.update_all wants_email: true
```

You can loop over the posts and update each post in a unique sql statement

```
  Post.joins(:comments).where(id: post_ids).each do |post|
    post.cached_comment_infos = post.comments.pluck(:author_name, :reference).map { |v| v.join("/") }.join(", ")
    post.save
  end
```

If you really want it to happen in one SQL statement you could look into the gem `activerecord-import`. You would need to use their 'duplicate key update' feature: https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import#duplicate-key-update

Comment: We can make this a bit more performant with `Post.joins(:comments).eager_load(:comments).each {|post| post.update(:cached_comment_infos, post.comments.map {|c| "#{c.author_name}/#{c.reference}"}.join(', ') }` it will at least save the N + 1 for loading the comments in the loop (but not the N update statements for the post object)